# SQLAlchemy Relationship

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from app import db
from flask import g
from datetime import datetime

ROLE_USER = 0
ROLE_ADMIN = 1

tags = db.Table('tags',
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tag.id'))
)

employees = db.Table('employees',
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('company_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('company.id'))
)

categories_to_company = db.Table('categories_to_company',
    db.Column('company_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('company.id')),
    db.Column('category_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('category.id'))
)

subcategories_to_company = db.Table('subcategories_to_company',
    db.Column('company_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('company.id')),
    db.Column('subcategory_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('sub_category.id'))
)

class Company(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    creator = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), index = True, unique = True)
    employees = db.relationship('User', secondary = 'employees', backref = db.backref('employees', lazy = 'dynamic')) 
    dateofcreation = db.Column('dateofcreation', db.DateTime)
    categories = db.relationship('Category', secondary = 'categories_to_company', backref = db.backref('categories', lazy = 'dynamic'))
    subcategories = db.relationship('SubCategory', secondary = 'subcategories_to_company', backref = db.backref('subcategories', lazy = 'dynamic'))

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.creator = g.user.id
        self.dateofcreation = datetime.utcnow()

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index = True, unique = True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(160))
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index = True, unique = True)
    registered_on = db.Column('registered_on' , db.DateTime)
    role = db.Column(db.SmallInteger, default = ROLE_USER)
    tags = db.relationship('Tag', secondary = 'tags', backref = db.backref('tags', lazy = 'dynamic'))

    def __init__(self, username, password, email):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.email = email
        self.registered_on = datetime.utcnow()

    def has_tag(self, tag):
        if not tag or not tag in self.tags:
            return False
        return True

    def set_tag(self, tag):
        if not self.has_tag(tag):
            self.tags.append(tag)
            return self
        else:
            return None

    def leave_tag(self, tag):
        if self.has_tag(tag):
            self.tags.remove(tag)
            return self
        else:
            return None

    def to_json(self):
        return {
            "id" : self.id,
            "firstname" : self.firstname,
            "lastname" : self.lastname,
            "email" : self.email,
            }

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True
    def is_active(self):
        return True
    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False
    def get_id(self):
        return unicode(self.id)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % (self.username)

class Category(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name =  db.Column(db.String(64), index = True, unique = True)

    def to_json(self):
        return {
            "id" : self.id,
            "name" : self.name}
    def from_json(self, source):
        if 'name' in source:
            self.name = source['name']

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Category %r>' % (self.name)

class SubCategory(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name =  db.Column(db.String(64), index = True)
    parentId = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('category.id'))

    def to_json(self):
        return {
            "id" : self.id,
            "name" : self.name,
            "pid" : self.parentId}
    def from_json(self, source):
        if 'name' in source:
            self.name = source['name']
        if 'pid' in source:
            self.parentId = source['pid']

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<SubCategory %r>' % (self.name)

class Tag(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name =  db.Column(db.String(64), index = True, unique = True)
    disabled = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)

    def to_json(self):
        return {
            "id" : self.id,
            "name" : self.name}
    def from_json(self, source):
        if 'name' in source:
            self.name = source['name']

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Tag %r>' % (self.name)
```

-//-//-//-//-
Дастаю данные так.

```
@app.route('/company/<int:id>/categories', methods = ['GET'])
def show_company(id):
u = Category.query.filter(Category.categories.any(Company.id==id)).all()
    todo_list = map(Category.to_json, u)
    return json.dumps(todo_list)
```

Получаю результат:

```
    [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Компьютер и ноутбук"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Программное обеспечение"
    }
]
```

Как сделать чтобы я получал дочерние элементы категорий, которые "выбрала" компании, и являются в то же время дочерними элементами компании

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Компьютер и ноутбук",
        "subcategories": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Консультации"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Настройка"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Программноеобеспечение"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить связь между объектами (через relationships) и сделать то же самое в методе to_json у Category. А лучше объединить эти 2 сущности в одну.

```py
class Category(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name =  db.Column(db.String(64), index = True, unique = True)

    def to_json(self):
        return {
            "id" : self.id,
            "name" : self.name,
            "subcategories": map(SubCategory.to_json, self.subcategories)
        }
    def from_json(self, source):
        if 'name' in source:
            self.name = source['name']

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Category %r>' % (self.name)

class SubCategory(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name =  db.Column(db.String(64), index = True)
    parentId = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('category.id'))
    category = db.relationship('Category', backref = 'subcategories')

    def to_json(self):
        return {
            "id" : self.id,
            "name" : self.name,
            "pid" : self.parentId}
    def from_json(self, source):
        if 'name' in source:
            self.name = source['name']
        if 'pid' in source:
            self.parentId = source['pid']

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<SubCategory %r>' % (self.name)
```

**UPD:**

Одной таблицы `category` достаточно. Для генерации json без рекурсии можно взять уже готовый вариант http://sqlalchemy-mptt.readthedocs.org/

```py
from sqlalchemy_mptt.mixins import BaseNestedSets

class Category(db.Model, BaseNestedSets):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name =  db.Column(db.String(64), index = True, unique = True)
    children = relationship(
        "Category",
        backref=backref('parent', remote_side=[id])
    )

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Category %r>' % (self.name)

jqTree_json = Category.get_tree(db.Session, json=True)  # Полное JSON дерево
```

Comment: А как доставать? Проблема в том что я эти сущности в другом месте построчно вывожу. В виде выпадающих меню. И они переодически редактируются и добавляются. Потом построчный вывод доставит хлопот.

Comment: Вы второй кто предлагает объединить

Comment: Доставать по связи между объектами (parent, childs). Например my_category.childs. Стандартное бинарное дерево http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/self_referential.html

Comment: Все категории не имеют родителей поэтому список можно достать так query(Category).filter(Category.parent_id._is(None)). Все подкатегории query(Category).filter(Category.parent_id._isnot(None))

Comment: Если категорий будет много то рекурсия не подойдет. Можно взять http://sqlalchemy-mptt.readthedocs.org/ и метод который генерирует JSON http://sqlalchemy-mptt.readthedocs.org/en/master/sqlalchemy_mptt.html#sqlalchemy_mptt.mixins.BaseNestedSets.get_tree

Comment: Может быть Вы подскажите другой вариант как это лучше хранить? Наверно у меня сам подход не тот.

Comment: @freenetwork, я же вам в предыдущем вашем вопросе расписал, как категории хранить, чтоб не вводить лишнюю сущность. Все, что вы делаете, можно сделать с той моделью данных.